Single exclamation mark in kotlin confusion
This is not a duplicate of any of the dozens questions with that title, which I have studied.
(1) Sorry if I am dense but bear with me, as i haven't been able to understand clearly the difference between ? and !, after reading about everything:
For instance, a common exclamation is:

?: I dont know whether it is null or not.
!: Be careful! This might be null as this is coming from Java.
!!: Be careful, and yes I know it. This is always not null.

But then, wouldn't this mean that ? and ! mean actually the same logical thing, that the variable can be null or not.
(2)  So now I got a function in java that returns this
 kotlin.Array<(out) java.security.cert.X509Certificate!>?

because each certificate in the array may or may not be null
Then why would I not be able to just assign into a variable as so:
 kotlin.Array<(out) java.security.cert.X509Certificate?>?

Which would tell kotlin that, drum roll, each certificate may or may not be null.
So here is the question, I got:
val c1  = javafunction()
Where c1 is of the type kotlin.Array<(out) java.security.cert.X509Certificate!>?

How can I assign c1 into c2:
val c2 : kotlin.Array<(out) java.security.cert.X509Certificate?>? = XXXX


What do you mean by "how can I assign c1 into c2"? What happens when you just do c2 = c1?

c2 = c1 fails (compilation error) because compiler refuses to assign a java.security.cert.X509Certificate! object into an java.security.cert.X509Certificate? object.
This is what puzzles me, because we are just assigning an array of nullable objects into an array of nullable object. That is object you have to check for null pointer.
Which mean I have to create an ArrayList then assign everything by hand etc... that definitely sounds like a hack, that doesn't feel right.

I cannot reproduce that. Please show a [mcve] - something I can directly copy and paste into a new project and reproduce your error.

Same, I got java function that returns array and can freely assign it to both Array and Array<Type?>

Can you post the exact error message? This doesn’t even seem related to ! because you are trying to assign it to something with <out Foo?>, which doesn’t even claim non-nullability and would therefore be less restrictive. Also, why do you have “out” in parentheses in your example code of the c2 declaration? That would not be compileable.

By the way (I'm not sure if you already know this), the single exclamation mark ! is not part of the Kotlin language syntax, but just a hint shown in IntelliJ IDEA that a certain type comes from Java and is therefore omitted from the usual nullability checks.

? means "it is nullable, i.e. it can be null or not null", ! means "it can be nullable or not nullable". See the difference? A value come from java can be non-nullable, i.e. there is zero possibilities for it to be null, but you don't know it. Not knowing it is non-nullable doesn't make it nullable, you just don't know. Schrödinger's nullability.

"This might be null as this is coming from Java." is a wrong statement. A function which never return null in java will never return null in kotlin. Just because you import a java function into kotlin doesn't magically make it return null in any cases.

! means it could be null but the compiler is not going to enforce null-safety restrictions on it. It will allow you to directly invoke its functions without using null-safe ?. calls, and it will allow you to assign it to non-nullable variable types. So there should be no problem doing c2 = c1 in your example.
In Java, we generally have the convention that a public function that could return null states that in its documentation, and we otherwise can treat it as non-nullable. So the ! allows us to work with Java return values the same way we would in Java.


?, !, and !! have subtly different meanings; they're also three different sorts of token:

? is a suffix for a type or type parameter, simply meaning “This type is nullable.”  (Without it, a type is guaranteed not to be null, though a type parameter may or may not be nullable.)
! is also a type suffix, but a special one that you can't write in your code; the compiler infers it for values coming from Java and other JVM languages, where there's no annotation to say whether it's nullable or not, and so the compiler can't tell.  The language calls this a ‘platform type’, and it means roughly “Be careful; I can't tell whether this could be null or not.”  (It would be safest to always assume nullable — but that would make many Java libraries a pain to use, and so the compiler reserves judgement.)
!! is a postfix operator that you apply to a value.  Strictly, it means: “If this value is null, then throw a NullPointerException; otherwise, treat it as non-nullable.”  However, people mostly use it to mean “Trust me, compiler: this value can never be null.”  As you can imagine, that makes it a little dangerous, which is why it's intended to look a bit ugly.  (In practice, it's a code smell.  It's usually better to check for null and handle it properly, e.g. with ?: — or, better, to use non-nullable values.)

A couple of related tokens you might get those confused with:

?: is the ‘Elvis operator’.  It means ‘…or, if that was null, then…’ — it uses the left-hand value unless that's null, in which case it uses the right-hand value.
.? is the ‘safe-call operator’.  It's like the normal . operator to call a function or property, except that the left-hand value can be nullable; if that's null, it skips the call and just uses the null instead.


Array interoperability is tricky in Kotlin.  This is partly because of platform types (see above), but also because Kotlin is stricter about array variance than Java.  (In Java, arrays are covariant, which can cause the compiler to miss type errors.  In Kotlin, they're invariant for that reason.)
But in this case, I think it's just a syntax issue.  Note that, like the !, the (out) is just an indicator from the compiler about the variance of the platform type; you can't use it like that in your code.
Without some context, I can't recreate your code, but I'd suggest simply trying this:
 val c2: Array<X509Certificate?>? = XXXX

Because the XXXX is a platform type, Kotlin won't complain about the potential mismatch in variable and nullability (assuming you know what you're doing).
You could omit the second ? if you know that the Java function will always return an array object.  (In this case, the first one is needed, since you say that the array can contain null elements.)
(Generally speaking, in Kotlin it's much better to use Lists than Arrays; Lists are much better supported in the standard library, have multiple implementations, have decent toString() etc. implementation; play nicely with generics; can be immutable; and so on.  The only times you need to deal with arrays are for low-level implementation, for varargs, and for interoperability with Java code and libraries like this.)


